# Enable to compile sdl 1.2 project on macbook

Tags: c, macos, gcc, compilation, sdl

I try this :

```
g++ -Wall affichage.c -o game -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/Cellar/sdl/1.2.15_1/SDL
```

but I have this error :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_SDL_EnableKeyRepeat", referenced from:
      chargement_objets(img*, img*) in affichage-50cd48.o
  "_SDL_Flip", referenced from:
      affiche_menu(img, img) in affichage-50cd48.o
      _SDL_main in affichage-50cd48.o


gcc Version : 
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.8)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.0.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

sdl installed in : /usr/local/Cellar/sdl/1.2.15_1

Mac OS Catalina

Answer (score 0):

Undefined symbols errors happen at **link** time.
So just like specifying header lookup path as `-I/usr/local/Cellar/sdl/1.2.15_1/SDL` , which helps at compile time, specify the library search path as `-L/usr/local/Cellar/sdl/1.2.15_1/SDL/lib` or something like this pointing to the right path. You may also need to add something like `-lSDL` to specify the library in which the functions you used are. Note that -l**SDL** means link against lib**SDL**.a